# How to use alternatives on linux - CentOS 6?

Tags: linux, centos, alternatives

I am trying to configure python to 3.9 on CentOS 6.

Here is my steps:

```
[root@quickstart ~]# alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/local/bin/python3.9 10
[root@quickstart ~]# alternatives --config  python
    
There is 1 program that provides 'python'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/local/bin/python3.9

Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 1
[root@quickstart ~]# alternatives --display python
python - status is manual.
 link currently points to /usr/local/bin/python3.9
/usr/local/bin/python3.9 - priority 10
Current `best' version is /usr/local/bin/python3.9.
[root@quickstart ~]# alternatives  --set python /usr/local/bin/python3.9
```

But when I issue python --version, still is 2.6

```
[root@quickstart ~]# python --version
**Python 2.6.6**
[root@quickstart ~]#
```

EDIT: even following the steps, the $PATH still has the python 2.6 in the first argument. Could be it? where is the $PATH configured? neither /etc/bashrc or ~/.bashrc doesn't have it.

```
[root@quickstart ~]# whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.6-config /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python2.6 /usr/local/bin/python3.9-config /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/local/lib/python3.9 /usr/include/python2.6 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
[root@quickstart ~]#
```

EDIT 2:
The /etc/alternatives has the python as 3.9, but not globaly.

```
[root@quickstart alternatives]# pwd
/etc/alternatives
[root@quickstart alternatives]# ./python --version
Python 3.9.10
[root@quickstart alternatives]# python --version
Python 2.6.6
[root@quickstart alternatives]#
```

Comment: What is your `$PATH`? Could it be that the v2 `python` is in a directory preceding `/usr/bin/`? OR: Did you by any chance not yet clear `bash`'s path hashes and thus still go for the old python? If so `type python` will say it is hashed, then clear via `hash -d python` or check for proper python version in a new terminal tab.

Comment: I've tried the "Change the Python3 default version in Ubuntu", still not working. Actually is an CentOS 6.7.

Comment: @GAD3R the OP is using a RedHat based system so Debian/Ubuntu solutions won't help.

Comment: I guess that puting /usr/local/bin ahead in PATH might do it (e.g. `PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` ).

Comment: I couldn't reproduce (rhel 8.2) `the primary link for python must be /usr/bin/unversioned-python`

Answer (score 1):

Add python2.6 to alternatives:

```
sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/local/bin/python2.6 5
```

Then set python3.9 as defaut:

```
sudo alternatives --config  python
```

Or override the symlink with the desired python version:

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python3.9 /usr/bin/python
```